# Excel - Get array, except for FALSE values

Tags: excel

I have the following columns:

[image]

The 3rd and 4th columns change based on some criteria (irrelevant for this question). As you can see in the above picture, some of the rows appear with the value FALSE.

What happens is that when I insert these values in a chart the values FALSE will appear in my chart as a bunch of 0s.

[image]

I know that I can use the Name Manager to create a dynamic array, but I need to find a way to **get an array with only the values different from FALSE**. This way my chart will start showing the values after 1.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using office 365 this can easily be done internally without coding using the new FILTER function.
Simply use this code where you want the filtered data to reside:

```
=FILTER(A:D,C:C<>FALSE)
```

And you are done

(my answer assumes your array begins in A1).

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim arr as variant
iRow = 2  'This will start at where your data starts
redim arr(0)
DoUntil Isempty(cells(iRow,2))  'Obviously your column will change dep. on where your data is
    if cells(iRow,2) <> FALSE then
        arr(ubound(arr)) = cells(iRow,2)
        redim preserve arr(ubound(arr)+1)
    end if
    iRow = iRow+2
Loop
```

That'll leave you with an array (with one blank entry at the end) of non FALSE values.

If you use a check on whether the array is empty then you can reorder the redim and remove the last blank entry. I haven't included it for verbosity of answer.